# How to create a desktop-shortcut with a START command?

Tags: windows, command-line-arguments, shortcut-file

I have a special situation where I must create a desktop shortcut that can run a special "START" command that I have tested on command line.

But the syntax that starts with "Start ..." is not accepted by the desktop shortcut creation dialog. How to solve this problem?

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, that works! However, there is a small blink when the command line window comes and goes.

Comment: @HansPassant I solved this problem by making the shortcut option Run to minimized. Thank you for the right direction. If you post your answer, I can mark it as answer with this comment.